# Access denied for cross account S3 access from EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to set up S3 cross account access and inspite of reading through all the [documentation](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3) and answers here somehow I am not able to make it work.

I have account AccountA (AccountId: AAAAAAAAAA) which has a S3 bucket.

The other AWS account, AccountB (AccountId: BBBBBBBBBB) has an application running on EC2. This application has to write files in the S3 bucket in AccountA.

The region of the bucket in AccountA is different from the region in which the EC2 is running in AccountB. As is norm now, the bucket is encrypted by AWS. Nothing special done by me there.

What I have done till now (just to test I have put all s3 permissions)
In Account A:

A bucket policy for S3 bucket in question.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-sample-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-sample-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

A role called **cross_account_access_role** has been created in Account A to which this policy is attached. This role **cross_account_access_role** has following trust policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::BBBBBBBBBB:role/test_ec2_role"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

In **AccountB** this is what I have got.
A policy which has permissions for local bucket as well as cross account access.

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::incoming-data",
            ],
            "Sid": "1"
        },
        {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::AAAAAAAAAA:role/cross_account_access_role",
            "Sid": "3"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

I have created a role in AccountB called **ec2_role**. This role has got above policy along with **`AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore`** attached to it under permissions policies.

The trust policy attached to this role is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Having done all that when I log into the EC2 instance (running in AccountB) and try to list the s3 bucket (in AccountA) contents I get a permission denied.

```
aws s3 ls //test-sample-bucket

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied
```

Any ideas where I might be messing up?

Comment: The Bucket Policy you are showing doesn't have a `Principal` entry, which makes me think it is actually a policy attached to an IAM User or an IAM Role, rather than being a Bucket Policy?

Comment: Oh. I will test and report back. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation is:

- Bucket in Account-A
- EC2 instance in Account-B
- Software running on the EC2 instance should be able to access the Bucket

You simply need:

- An **IAM Role** (`Role-B`) on the EC2 instance in Account-B that gives it permission to use the S3 bucket
- A **Bucket Policy** on the bucket (`Bucket-A`) in Account-A that gives permission for the IAM Role `Role-B` to use the bucket

The **IAM Role in Account-B** (that is attached to the EC2 instance) would look something like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It is granting permission for the EC2 instance to access `Bucket-A`. You can add permissions as necessary (eg `GetObject` and `ListBucket`). Try not to grant `s3:*` if possible.

The **Bucket Policy on `Bucket-A`** would look something like:

```json
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Principal":{
            "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::BBBBBBBBBB:role/Role-B"
         },
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:PutObject"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a/*",
      }
   ]
}
```

It is granting `Role-B` permission to access the bucket.

The above method will use the existing role assigned to the EC2 instance without any need to 'assume' any roles.

**KMS Note:** Amazon S3 recently introduced encryption by default. It is *possible* that this will impact the ability to access `Bucket-A`. If you receive any errors about KMS keys, you will need to add permissions in KMS to allow the key to be used by `Role-B`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will test it out. Is it possible to have a clean bucket policy and manage the cross account access using roles, trust policies and assume roles? What I understood from reading documentation is that it is the cleanest, more flexible and easy to maintain. I might be wrong though.

Comment: I provided what I consider the "easiest" method because the software can simply access the S3 bucket without needing to assume any Roles. It can also be used to copy objects from S3 buckets in Account-B to the bucket in Account-A. The alternate approach is for the software on the EC2 instance to assume a role from Account-A, extract the returned credentials and then use those credentials to access the S3 bucket. This means that, when you try to access the bucket using the AWS CLI, you would first need to call `aws sts assume-role`, then store those credentials in a new profile and use them.

Comment: Can we add "Principal" to a S3 bucket policy. I got an error "This policy contains the following error: Has prohibited field Principal". The principal is expected to be part of the Trust policy attached to the Role_A defined in Account A. If I need Role_A. I think as per your post I can do without it.

Comment: A "Bucket Policy" is added to a **Bucket** in the S3 management console. I suspect that you are attempting to add a policy to an **IAM Role** (which means it is _not_ a 'Bucket Policy' -- it is simply a policy that refers to a bucket, but is placed elsewhere). A policy placed directly onto an IAM User or IAM Role does not contain a `Principal` because it is implied by the entity on which it is placed. An S3 Bucket Policy is placed on a Bucket and _does_ require a Principal.

Comment: Thanks for that. I corrected my mistake and it is working now. Other applications also write to the bucket. I am wondering if attaching a policy to this bucket will cut off access to other roles and users who write to this bucket.

Comment: Merely adding another `Allow` statement to a Bucket Policy will not remove any existing access. If it currently does _not_ have a Bucket Policy, adding a Bucket Policy containing `Allow` statements will not remove any existing access. Only `Deny` statements will reduce access.